# Submit value through script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple input box

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

The code of button that has submits the value of name is

```
<script
    src="my_url"
    data-name=" value that user puts should come here "
    data-buttontext="Add Name">
</script>
```

I wish that as soon as the user puts the value in input it should get assigned to data-name

Can anyone please tell how it can be done

Comment: you can use `keypress event` using a jQuery please refer to https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: is the `data-name` in your script tag??

Answer (score 0):

Assign data-name to text value within script :

```
data-name = $("[name='name']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='name']").keyup(function(e){
   var currval = $(this).val();
   $("button").data("name",currval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should help

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keypress(function(){
        data-name=" value that user puts should come here "
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like.

```js
$(document).on('keyup','[name=name]',function(ev){
var value = $(this).val();
  $('[src=my_url]').attr('data-name', value);
  console.log($('[src=my_url]').attr('data-name'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="my_url"  data-name=" value that user puts should come here " data-buttontext="Add Name">
</script>

<input type="text" name="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `Id` attribute set to your script and input tags so its easy for you to bind `keyup` event on the input and also find the right script tag for proper update.

```js
$('#myInput').on('keyup',function(e){
  $('#myScript').data('name', $(this).val());
  //for test
  alert($('#myScript').data('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="myScript" src="my_url"  data-name=" value that user puts should come here " data-buttontext="Add Name">
</script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" name="name">
```